# Not attending to US university. Can I use my F-1 visa for a transit flight?

Tags: usa, transit, change-purpose-of-travel

I have an F-1 Visa but I will not attend the university because I couldn't get an scholarship. Instead I will attend a university at France. Could I use my F-1 visa to enter the US to make a connection flight? Would it be valid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. An F-1 visa is valid for study. You can only use it to enter the US when you are properly enrolled at an authorized institution and they have indicated this status in the [SEVIS](https://iss.washington.edu/immigration/sevis) database. When you arrive at the port of entry, the officer will check the database and you may well be denied entry.

If your nationality is such that you need a visa to transit the United States, you'll need to apply for a new visa.

Comment: ...or find a way to travel to France without a connection in the US.

Comment: There are at least a dozen possible MEX-CDG routings, with dozens of flights daily, only a few of which transit the US. This ought to be pretty easy.

Comment: Sure, they are way more expensive, though.

Comment: @ARamirez I found an Air France MEX-CDG nonstop at $28,475 ($1,530 USD) one way. I guess this is expensive, but as airfares go, it's not completely insane. And it is premium economy. And strangely, the flights with connections seem to cost the same or even more.

Comment: @Joe Anybody who needs a visa to enter the US would need a visa to transit the US (the US does not have international transits without going through immigration). Mexico is not a [visa waiver program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program) country and would need a significantly lower visa refusal rate before it would be eligible.